# discord.py get server id with on_ready() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to load some information about a server from a json file, each server is identified within this file by its guild.id.
However if I want to try and load some data at the start with on_ready(), I cant use ctx, which I need to get the current servers guild.id, so I can identify it within the file.

(sorry if that's a bad explanation but just look at line 6 of my code and you'll understand what I'm trying to do)

Here is my current code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    with open("server_info.json", "r") as infoRaw:
        infoJson = json.load(infoRaw)
        for server in infoJson["Servers"]: #search each server data
            if (server["id"] == ctx.message.guild.id): #compare id in file to current id (error line)
                data = server[data]
                break
```

I cant find any other ways online of getting the the servers id without a user sending a message first.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately from what I'm understanding, what you're trying to achieve isn't possible with the `on_ready()` function. This is because this isn't a function that's dependent on a server.

Comment: @goose.mp4 Thanks for the clarification, what do you think would be the best way to load this data then? I would assume checking every message/command if you have the data or not and if you don't, getting it?

Comment: Hi DataGraph. You want to run a code on a specific server when the bot launches, or do you want to run a piece of code on each individual server the bot is on?

Answer (score 2):

You can use discord.utils, which would look like the following:

```py
guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, id=378473289473829)
```

You can use what every ID you want, just be sure to replace `bot` with the name of your Client instance.
This works in on_ready, without any ctx

Answer (score 1):

You could use `bot.guilds` which is a list of all guilds the bot is in and then check if the ID matches with an extra loop

Comment: Or just use discord.utils.get which replaces the loop

Comment: Yeah I forgot about that xD